# Create Brush by combining other brushes (gradients, etc.)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, staticresource, imagebrush

an app uses a background which is composed from a background color, a linar gradient and two radial gradient (looks better that it sounds :). Since this background is used on all pages I would like to define it once and than re-use it on all pages.

My first solution was to create a UserControl and apply the color and the gradient on it. I can then use this control on all pages as background.

This works fine but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. Is it somehow possible to combine multiple brushes to one? I could then simply Apple "MyCombinedBrush" to the page directly instead of using an extra UserControl.

I found information that one could create an image and use it to create an ImageBrush. Unfortunately everything I found is limited to WPF and does not work on Windows Phone.

Is there any "elegant" way to solve this or is the UserControl the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - you can use ImageBrush on WP. (Although I've not tried this)

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="72">
  <TextBlock.Foreground>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="forest.jpg"/>
  </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is one solution I worked out - it has some disadvantages but works quite well and allows you to play quite well with many Brushes:

```
 Canvas canvasToBeBrush = new Canvas();
 canvasToBeBrush.Width = 300;
 canvasToBeBrush.Height = 300;
 Rectangle firstBrush = new Rectangle();
 firstBrush.Width = 200;
 firstBrush.Height = 200;
 firstBrush.Fill = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.Blue, Colors.Brown);
 Rectangle secondBrush = new Rectangle();
 secondBrush.Width = 200;
 secondBrush.Height = 200;
 secondBrush.Opacity = 0.5;
 secondBrush.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
 canvasToBeBrush.Children.Add(firstBrush);
 canvasToBeBrush.Children.Add(secondBrush);
 WriteableBitmap bitmapToBrush = new WriteableBitmap(canvasToBeBrush, null);
 ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
 myBrush.ImageSource = bitmapToBrush;
 LayoutRoot.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: Getting in Image into an ImageBrush is not problem. But this is not the question. My Background is drawn using multiple Brusches (SolidBrush + Gradients). How can I create a combinded Brush? I found information saying that this would be possible by drawing the desired Pattern to an Image and using this as input for an ImageBrush. I do not know how to do this on WP. If there are any other solutions that do not use an ImageBrush this would be fine as well of course.

Comment: I've added one solution (still using ImageBrush) but works fine.